# Hibernate with PostgreSQL database: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, maven

I am trying to connect my PostgreSQL database with hibernate framework but I'm encountering the following error. I tried with the previous posted questions and suggestions from the forum but I can't help myself. (I am using spring framework in Eclipse)

> UserDetails

```
package sample.hibernate.dto;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity

public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    private int userid;
    private String userName;
    public int getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }
    public void setUserid(int userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

}
```

> HibernateTest

```
package com.sample.hibernate;
import sample.hibernate.dto.UserDetails;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserid(1);
        user.setUserName("First User");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

> Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">   

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <!-- <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
                    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/TestDB</property> -->

        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080/utilitydb</property>
        <property name="connection.username"></property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresSQLDialect
        </property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
        <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
        <property name="cache.use_structured_entries">true</property>
        <property name="cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
        <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/hibernate-config/ehcache.xml</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/Event.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/Person.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/PhoneNumber.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/Account.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/HolidayCalendar.hbm.xml"/>

        <mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/Item.hbm.xml"/>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Name the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="sample.hibernate.dto.UserDetails"/>


    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

> Maven Dependencies

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebCrawler</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Entity recent -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- J UNIT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- J SOUP -->
        <dependency>
              <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
              <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
              <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
              <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- POSTgreSQL JDBC -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

> Error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2160)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2077)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2056)
    at tut.fast.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:16)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 59; columnNumber: 23; The content of element type "session-factory" must match "(property*,mapping*,(class-cache|collection-cache)*,event*,listener*)".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2157)
    ... 3 more
```

> after some suggestion I have made changes in cfg.XML document

```
<!-- Database connection settings -->
<!-- <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/TestDB</property> -->

<property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080/utilitydb</property>
<property name="connection.username"></property>
<property name="connection.password"></property>

<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

<!-- SQL dialect -->
<property name="dialect">
    org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresSQLDialect
</property>

<!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

<property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="cache.use_structured_entries">true</property>
<property name="cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
<property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/hibernate-config/ehcache.xml</property>
<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>

<!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>

<!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>


<mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/Event.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/Person.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/PhoneNumber.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/Account.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/HolidayCalendar.hbm.xml"/>

<mapping resource="hibernate-config/domain/Item.hbm.xml"/>


<!-- Name the annotated entity class -->
<mapping class="tut.fast.vivek.hibernate.dto.UserDetails"/>
```

> , but still I am getting some errors,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: hibernate-config/domain/Event.hbm.xml not found
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:769)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2257)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2229)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2209)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2162)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2077)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2056)
at tut.fast.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:16)
```

Comment: What is your file structure?

Comment: HibernateModel
   -src/main/java
     - com.sample.hibernate(package)
         -HibernateTest.java
     - sample.hibernate.dto(package)
         -UserDetails

Comment: Have you tried `<mapping resource="/hibernate-config/domain/Item.hbm.xml"/>`

Comment: HibernateModel
   -src/main/java
   <<  - com.sample.hibernate(package)
         -HibernateTest.java
     - sample.hibernate.dto(package)
         -UserDetails
         hibernate.cfg.xml  >>
   -src/main/resource
   -src/test/java
   -JRE System Library
   -Maven Dependencies
   -src <<-main, -test >>
   -target
   -pom.xml

Comment: `MappingNotFoundException` says that  it has not found `hibernate-config/domain/Event.hbm.xml` at the specified location check proper path

Comment: yes @Jens I tried... but same error..<< Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: hibernate-config/domain/Event.hbm.xml not found >>

Comment: @xrcwrn, I tried but the same error..<< Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: hibernate-config/domain/Event.hbm.xml not found >>

Comment: @xrcwrn, I changed the file structure but getting some different error..<< Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
 at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2095)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2076)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2056)
 at tut.fast.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:17) >>